# How can I pass dictionary from one view controller class to another?SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary

I am trying to make a list of users and their passwords in one view controller, save that information in a dictionary, and send that dictionary to another view controller which asks the user to input their username/password combination to authorize the log in. (the key is the username and the value is the password). Is there a way I can send the dictionary from SecondVC to the FirstVC?

```
First View Controller

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var Username: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Verification: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        Username.delegate = self
        Password.delegate = self

    }
    
    var usersDict = [String : String]()
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let des = segue.destination as? AccountViewController {
            des.usersDict = usersDict
        }
    }
    


    @IBAction func Authorization(_ sender: Any) { 
        for ( key , value ) in usersDict{
            let v = key.count
            var start = 0
            if start <= v{
                if Username.text == key{
                    if Password.text == value{
                        Verification.text = "Looks Good"
                    }
                }
                else{
                    start += 1
                }
            }
            else{
                Verification.text = "Yikes"
            }
            
            
        }
        


    }
    
}
```

```
Second View Controller
class AccountViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var CreateUsername: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var CreatePassword: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CreateUsername.delegate = self
        CreatePassword.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    var usersDict = [ String : String ]()

    @IBAction func MakeANewAccount(_ sender: Any) {
        usersDict[CreateUsername.text!] = CreatePassword.text!
    }
    

}
```

I have made there dictionary, but it will only send in the beginning and won't update after creating the original account. (dictionary it is sending is empty)

Comment: Share your code and your attempt to do so

Comment: There are quite a few different ways to do this. Which to use depends on how you are linking from SecondVC to the FirstVC.

Comment: Post the code that links the user from first view controller to second view controller.

Comment: Do you have a segue ?

Comment: I didn't use any code I used transitions from one to the next and back using buttons and dragging across.

Comment: Yes @Sh_Khan I have a segue.

Answer (score 1):

With a segue add this method inside `ViewController`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let des = segue.destination as? AccountViewController {
        des.usersDict = yourDicHere
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code. For clarification, when you wrote yourDicHere I have to create a new dictionary in the ViewController right?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but wasn't the dictionary supposed to go in the other direction?

Comment: @PhillipMills op wrote first and second above each vc `usersDict ` is the placeholder in the second vc

Comment: Since he created the dictionary in second, I assumed he wanted to send it back to first for authorization.  Maybe not.  :)

Comment: @PhillipMills yeah I misinterpreted the code that Sh_Khan suggested to use. Now I have come back to my code and it isn't sending it back(which is what I thought the code did). Using Khan's code I was able to send it, however the updated dictionary after adding another account didn't. Is there a way where I can send the updated dictionary rather than just in the beginning because if I do send it in the beginning it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general pattern for making a controller work with data from some object it creates, in this case a second controller.

Try applying it to your situation and let me know if you run into problems.

```
protocol Processor {
    func process(_ dict: [String : String])
}

class FirstController: UIViewController, Processor {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? SecondController {
            controller.delegate = self
        } else {
            print("Unexpected view controller \(segue.destination)")
        }
    }
    
    func process(_ dict: [String : String]) {
    }
}

class SecondController: UIViewController {
    var delegate: Processor?
    
    func someWork() {
        if let processor = delegate {
            processor.process(["Name" : "Pwd"])
        } else {
            print("Delegate not assigned")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am so sorry for asking simple questions, but where should I add this code(view controller, app delegate, etc.)? Also, do I only replace the (_dict : [String : String]) with usersDict or are there more areas where I have to use different variables.

Comment: This isn't copy/paste but rather a pattern for how your classes can interact with each other.  It's probably best if you try to understand what it's doing and apply the logic to what you have.

Comment: In my understanding, the Processor protocol defines the dictionary, in the code for the Second Controller I see that func someWork is accessing the func process within the protocol processor. After calling the dictionary within the protocol in processor, how do I refer to it again(to add the new usernames and passwords)? In the IBAction to refer to the dictionary I tried Processor.process[CreateUsername.text!] = CreatePassword.text! to add new entries, however it sends an error saying "value of type '(Processor) -> (String: String]) -> ()" has no subscripts". Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I changed the code to  processor.process([CreateUsername.text! : CreatePassword.text!])  and it doesn't throw any error messages. I still need help on how to reference the dictionary in the FirstViewController for the for-in loop (the for-in loop is to authorize the user and allow them to use the app). The way I understand  the template you gave me is sending the dictionary from the second view controller to the first using a protocol? Is my understanding correct?